# package.json and package-lock.json does not reflect node_module's versions

Tags: npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I updated my Angular project with `npm` and for some reason `package.json` and `package-lock.json` was not updated accordingly. So the question is, do I have to update them manually, or is there a way to update these files according to the actual versions in node_modules?

I tried `npm init` but that gives me a very big `package.json` containing every package in node_modules. Therefore I would prefer something that updates each entry in `package.json` according to what is actually installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, where not all of the needed modules in `node_modules` were "required" (directly or indirectly) by `package.json`, so every time I installed something using `npm install`, it also removed a whole bunch of modules.

My solution wasn't a very satisfactory one, but it did the trick:

1. Renamed my `package-lock.json` file and `package.json` files to keep them safe but out of the way.
2. Used `npm init` as you mentioned, to create a version of `package.json` that contained all of the modules in `node_modules`.
3. Moved that out of the way but kept it for reference.
4. Renamed `node_modules` to something else to keep it safe but out of the way.
5. Created a brand new `package.json` file, again using `npm init`, but which had no dependencies because there was now no `node_modules` directory.
6. Went through my source files finding every dependency `require` statement, and did an `npm --save install package@version` on each.  I got the package name from the `require` and then found it in the complete `package.json` (from steps 2 and 3) and used the version number from that to ensure it matched what was there before.  (I've got some legacy code with out-of-date modules, which is why I wanted specific versions.)
7. Now, my `package.json` file is minimal, but when I run `npm install`, everything is up to date.