# npm refuses to generate package-lock.json

Tags: ubuntu, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

If I update a dependency manually in the `package.json` or "automatically" (by installing a package through npm CLI) both methods do not update the `package-lock.json` leaving me with a broken `npm ci` build (inconsistencies between `package.json` and `package-lock.json` not allowed).

- NPM version 10.2.3
- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- We are working on an Angular/TypeScript project.

Things I have tried without a `package-lock.json` being updated (or created for that matter):

- `npm install --save-dev webpack`
- manually set the dependency in my `package.json` and run `npm install`
- try other commands such as `ng build <project> --configuration <any-env>` or `npm i` or `npm audit fix` etc.
- repeat any of the above commands with or without `npm_modules` and/or `dist` folder removed

My colleague, on macOS, does see updates of the `package-lock.json` file with `npm install` after manually changing a dependency in the `package.json` and I cannot figure out why.

I have read and tried solutions in the following topics without resolving:

- [package-lock.json not updated after removing a package from package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039455/package-lock-json-not-updated-after-removing-a-package-from-package-json)
- [Why does "npm install" rewrite package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json)
- [npm update is not updating the version in package.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734483/npm-update-is-not-updating-the-version-in-package-json-file)
- [package.json and package-lock.json does not reflect node_module's versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68892531/package-json-and-package-lock-json-does-not-reflect-node-modules-versions)
- [package-lock.json is rewritten after npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70095585/package-lock-json-is-rewritten-after-npm-install)

Comment: _"or created for that matter"_ - so there's no lock file to start with? Is it excluded from version control? Is there any local/global npm configuration (`.npmrc`) that says anything about lock file updates?

Comment: _"both methods do not update the package-lock.json"_ - there is one to start with (included in version control). It does not function as expected with or without the previous `package-lock.json` file present. 

But then you mentioned `.npmrc` ... and this lterally had the line `package-lock=false` in it :facepalm:. Thank you Jon - such a simple oversight that kept me busy for an hour. If you would transfer your comment to an answer I'd gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:** well this is embarrassing; don't have a `package-lock=false` in your `.npmrc`. The end.

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal as admin Follow the following lines:
1)npm cache clean --force
2)npm config list
3)npm ci
4)rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
5) npm install --save-dev webpack
6)npm install -g npm@latest
This will solve your error

Comment: I'm afraid your confidence does not transfer to my commandline.

1. Done
2. Done (although I don't think this command modifies any form of behaviour?)
3. Does not work as my `package-lock.json` is out of sync, also does not work if it is deleted
4. Done
5. Done, only updates the `package.json` ... as the problem describes
6. No-op ... I already have the latest NPM version.